# Ipe extensions (ipelets)

Tags: graphics, technical-drawing, ipe

I'm using ipe to draw a lot of figures and I find out that I can, for example, plot some functions.

What extensions do you use in Ipe? There are some already installed when we download it, but are there others useful?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- A list of useful ipelets by IPE author: https://github.com/otfried/ipe-wiki/wiki/Ipelets
- Creation of plots of functions (the most important from the list above): https://github.com/lahvak/ipeplots
- Useful stylesheets for paper sizes, dash styles, transparency and fonts: https://www.sthu.org/misc/ipe.html
- Electrical Engineering plots: https://github.com/christiankral/ElectricalEngineering.isy
- Gradients and additions: https://alga.win.tue.nl/tutorials/ipe/

Comment: One time I used IPE :-). Very good catch. :-)