# How can I draw a regular polygon using Ipe?

Tags: diagrams, polygon, ipe

Is there a way to easily draw a regular polygon using Ipe? The top toolbar has an icon for a polygon but not for a regular one, and manually aligning the vertices is a pain. The [documentation](https://ipe.otfried.org/manual/onepage.html) doesn't seem to contain the word "regular", and I couldn't find any appropriate [Ipelets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/576649/260837).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community What additional details should I add?

Comment: If using `ipe` is not mandatory, use other packages such as PSTricks or its friends (Asymptote, Metapost, TikZ, or even SkiaSharp).

Comment: @TheCodeMocker I'll check those out, thanks!

Comment: Use the ipelet, on goodies, "regular k-gon" on a circle.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest abandoning Ipe in this case. There are many ways to do this directly in LaTeX. Here is a possibility using `TikZ`:

Define a macro `\regpoly` that takes two arguments, one optional:

`\regpoly[<options>]{<num sides>}`

The options include color, rotation, scale, etc. Basically anything you can put into a `\draw` command. So for example, `\regpoly{6}\quad\regpoly{7}` will produce

[image]

and `\regpoly[red, thick, dotted, rotate=22.5, scale=.75]{8}` produces

[image]

`scale=1` corresponds to a radius of 1cm. With appropriate scaling you can use this inline as well:

`Here is a \regpoly[scale=.15]{6} in a sentence.`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\regpoly}[2][]{\tikz[baseline={(current bounding box.south)}]{\foreach \n[evaluate=\n as \t using 360/#2*\n] in {1,...,#2}{\draw[#1](\t:1)--(\t+360/#2:1);}}}

\begin{document}

\regpoly{6}\quad\regpoly{7}\qquad\regpoly[red, thick, dotted, rotate=22.5, scale=.75]{8}

Here is a \regpoly[scale=.15]{6} in a sentence.

\end{document}
```